# React Native - Registering components with AppRegistry

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native, but I noticed in the main index.js file, you register the App component. I see this as similar to attaching the App component to a root element in React. I know I still have to export each component I create, but do I have to call this line within every component as well?

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)
```

Comment: I don't think a starter kit is the best place to start if you haven't used React Native before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you only need to do it for your top level app component.

Comment: Hello, there is no AppRegistry used in the App.js in the newer React Native version. do I still need to use this in the App.js which is the main file of my React Native project? Or I just should use this in other components to export them in my App.js?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Recent React Native changes encourage react-navigation straight away instead.
Navigation.setRoot() and other similar methods